# java get graphical position of a character in a JTextComponent

Tags: java, swing

How can I get the position (in pixels) of the 7th (for example) character in a JTextComponent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Rectangle rectangle = textComponent.modelToView( 7 );
```

From the Rectangle you can get the x/y location.